# Observable 'wait' for another observable for access token and resubscribe

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am stuck on a problem and the situation is that I am calling Observable getFilms() and when the token has expired and it throws an onError I would like to ask another Observable for refresh token 'wait' and have this getFilms() method resubscribe.

I tried retryWhen but it is called 3 times which is not what I want and it doesn't give the desired effect even with setting the firstAttempt condition

`getFilms() .hereWaitForRefreshTokenObservable()  .~ .subscribe(films ->)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone gets here the solution to this is to use Authenticator correctly.

In my case I doubted its performance and spent a couple of hours trying to fix it in the RXJava layer.

I simply forgot to add the "Bearer" :

```
 .header("Authorization", "Bearer $newToken")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Observable 'wait' for another observable for access token and resubscribe

Answer to the question in the title:

```
getFilms()
    .onErrorResumeNext { ex ->
        if(ex is HttpException && ex.code() == 401){
            reauthorize()
                .flatMap { 
                    getFilms() 
                }
        } else {
            Observable.error(ex)
        }
    }
```

That's a very common pattern when using expiring access, like JWT.

Side note: I assume we're talking about http calls and in such case you probably should use `Maybe` (eventually `Single` or `Completable`) but not `Observable`. `Observable` is for sequences returning more than 1 element and a http call usually can't return more than 1 response. Not unless you have some very advanced cache that common clients lack.